# Android Gradle Error: "Failed to get application id for debug"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, synchronization

I recently updated android studio and now gradle won't sync with my project. Does anyone have any idea what this error message means?

Comment: i m not sure but try replacing packageName to applicationId in your build.gradle file maybe that solves your problem

Comment: Here was a similar question on this forum after an update to Android Studio: http://goo.gl/NUmMrn It may help you.

Comment: Check your AndroidManifest.xml file for any garbage. I had some lines in there that don't fit into the XML format. I removed and built, it worked.

Answer (score 8):

Check your androidmanifest.xml for errors. I had this issue when I missed a " from an attribute.

Comment: worked for me. apparently the tools attribute had disappeared!

Comment: This helped me too. My android manifest began "b<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>" so I must have hit the b key on accident.

Answer (score 1):

As Alec mentioned, there are errors with your androidmanifest.xml.

You can use the following link to validate your android manifest file.

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

```
\n (new line)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
....more xml code....
```

A new line in front of the XML file will cause this error as well (I learned it the hard way).

Answer (score 0):

After updating compiler version to 1.7 my `AndroidManifest.xml` seems to have been updated by gradle/AS  and ended up with a similar error "Failed to get application id for release".

The culprit was missing tools namespace, fixed by adding it back:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.my.android.app" ></manifest>
```